# SageMaker Neo Compilation - Unable to Neo Compile for FP16 and INT8 precision

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-compilers

I'm trying to Neo compile a Pytorch YoloV5 Large model for edge deployment on an Nvidia Jetson Xavier NX device. I'm able to do it using the default settings for FP32 precision but I'm unable to do it for FP16 or INT8 precision. I have tried passing it in "CompilerOptions" in the [OutputConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_OutputConfig.html) but the output of Neo compilation is still FP32.

How can I Neo compile the model for FP16 and INT8 precision ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Received a response from an AWS source](https://repost.aws/questions/QUTEYNFSxHTK2Z2JbHM8yUfw/sage-maker-neo-compilation-unable-to-neo-compile-for-fp-16-and-int-8-precision)

"Unfortunately Neo doesn't support quantization for Jetson Devices. It means you can only compile FP32 models and they will be FP32 after compilation.

I know this is not what you're looking for, but FYI, Neo supports int8 model optimization only for TFLite and targeting CPU not GPU. Check here some supported models: [https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sagemaker/latest/dg/neo-supported-edge-tested-models.html"](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sagemaker/latest/dg/neo-supported-edge-tested-models.html%22)